# Java: How to break the while loop in scrolling and printing the text till end of the page

Tags: java, selenium

I am not able to break the while loop in scrolling and printing the text till the end of the page. please help me out how to break the loop?

```
while(true) { 
        //js executor to scroll the page
        JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
        js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
        List<WebElement> restNameList = 
        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='nA6kb']"));
        for(WebElement e1 : restNameList) {
        //printing the text
        System.out.println(e1.getText()); 
         }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: use case is printing the names while scrolling the page till the page get ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
bool flag = true;
long lastHeight = 0;
long newHight = 0;
while (flag) {
    //js executor to scroll the page
    JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
    lastHeight = (long) js.executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");
    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
    // Do some waiting

    newHight = (long) js.executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");
    if (lastHeight == newHight) {
        flag = false;
    }
    
    lastHeight = newHight;
}

List < WebElement > restNameList =
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='nA6kb']"));
for (WebElement e1: restNameList) {
    //printing the text
    System.out.println(e1.getText());
}
```

Comment: it is not working i want to scroll and print the names of resturanat while scrolling till end of the page and then at the end i want to break the loop

Comment: i want to print all the text till the end of the page till the scrolling gets end till last

Comment: Does your page dynamically populate element while you scroll?

Comment: the above code is printing but loop is not breaking it keeps on running inifitnely thats where i am facing issue how to break loop after it got printed all the elements

Comment: I have edited the answer, you need to do the scrolling inside the loop. and get the hight of the page every time after some wait. the compare the new and old value if both are the same the all the elements are loaded, you need to return the value of the hight using the javascript

Comment: yes now the code looks fine just one small change if we are using int and typecasting in int it is giving class caste exception ....so i have used long instead of int code worked fine.. thankyou for effort and time

Answer (score 0):

Sloppy, but this should do the trick. I'm not sure what condition you want to use for breaking the loop, but here is very generic pseudocode.
You can set up a flag before the for loop. For instance:

```
while(true):

     flag = 0

     for (condition):

          if (condition2): 
               flag = 1
               break
          print("xyz")
     if flag = 1:
          break
```

Comment: it is not working i want to scroll and print the names of resturanat while scrolling till end of the page and then at the end i want to break the loop

Comment: i want to print all the text till the end of the page till the scrolling gets end till last

Comment: Why don't you add a simple  
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+Keys.END) to get to the bottom of the page immediately?

Comment: before that we have to print all the text which is coming through scrolling the page which i have to stored in a list

Comment: its not about one element its about printing element everytime whenver we are scrolling down